# how can i make 100% odorless tallow?

Tags: beef, fat, beef-tallow

i used fresh beef suet. **wet rendered twice**. i made sure to not increase the heat too much (it barely simmered). but its smell didn't go away.

it smells like beef fat. you might say x smells like x because it comes from x. that makes sense but i just wish to make the tallow smell&taste odorless or like at least butter

how can i make this happen? open to any and all ideas.

ps. i make tallow to eat (i'm on low carb), so i don't want to destroy fat soluble vitamins in it, or make it more unhealthy.

Comment: I don't think you can, especially not without some extensive chemistry (to remove the volatiles that make up the smell/taste), which would entirely change the tallow into something not tallow-like at all, but I'll leave this unanswered in case someone has a real idea.

Comment: @bob1 what if i add like 50grams of [black pepper, rosemary, red pepper, garlic powder] into 1kg of tallow? can that remove the smell? there are sausages with 40% fat content. none of them smell like tallow or fat

Comment: No, that might conceal the smell/taste to some extent, but it won't remove it.  BTW to me butter tastes buttery, a fairly mild but definitely present taste, so not no-taste.

Comment: @bob1, difference between spicy tallow and those sausages is that those sausages have lean meat in them. is that why are you saying that idea wouldn't be effective? btw my purpose is to not be disgusted by fat smell/taste. i'm very sensitive to it. butter mixed with egg yolk works AMAZING, but i'm looking for a backup fat source.

Comment: It sounds like your "real" question is for a delicately-flavored fat to use as an alternative for butter. There are likely a number of answers to that question, and I suspect it would be well received on this site. However you've asked specifically about making a strongly flavored fat not taste like itself, and to do so with minimal processing -- I don't think this is possible, and for that reason, I don't think this question is likely to be answered here.

Comment: If you take a big step backwards to describe your original "alternate for butter mixed with egg yolk," and what you're using it for, and what you want from a substitute, I think you'll find many more suitable answers. (Though likely none will involve beef fat)

Comment: @AMtwo, by fat source i meant for animal fat source for myself (not for a recipe or anything). producing tallow that doesn't smell/taste like beef meat fat is my goal. that's my goal because i'm disgusted by animal meat fat. sausages with 40% fat content taste fine to me. why can't i put a bunch of spice into tallow and make it taste fine, like those sausage makers?

Comment: There’s a difference between getting rid of the scent, and covering it up.  And you’re dealing with a product that’s always known to have a little bit of a smell. Have you considered changing to pork leaf lard?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, not at all. It would go against the law of physics.

The human sense of smell reacts to the chemical makeup of substances we are exposed to. Not every substance has a smell, but when a substance does have one, then there is no way for that smell to somehow be "turned off". Saying that you wish it were otherwise is like saying that you wish water to stop being wet - it won't get you any other answer.

Things you may have heard in relation to odor, such as the wet rendering, are not aimed at it being odorless, they are aimed at it not having off-smells. For example, if you use a high-heat method for rendering which crisps the fat-and-meat mixture, you will end up with a tallow smelling of fried meat (because there *will* be traces of fried meat in it). So these methods are not meant for creating odorless tallow, they are meant for creating tallow which smells of pure tallow.